# Using Schemas in SQL Server 2008/2012

Tags: sql-server, database-design, schema

I'm in the process of planning a small- to medium-sized database in SQL Server 2008 R2 and was recently watching a training video that had mentioned (briefly) the topic of Schemas.

Are they used for organizational purposes or security purposes?  I was thinking of using them in my design because I want to have an Archive section of my database where it will store data that is over 1 year old, but that still exists in the database.  And separate that from the "active" data tables, which will be data that is less than a year old.

I was thinking of creating two Schemas with identical table structures (the only difference being which Schema they are associated with) named "Archive", and the other being name something like "Current" (for the purpose of sorting out the data.  Is this a bad design idea or will it not matter?  (Or will SQL Server even allow the same table name, but in different schemas?)

Answer (score 0):

> "are they used for organizational purposes and/or security purposes"

- Both.

> "Can you have the same table name, but in two different schemas"

- Yes, you can. But I wouldn't if UNLESS (on re-reading with respect to the comments) it's some sort of archive schema in which case I would name the tables the same.

Comment: So I guess from your answer, I would probably be better off creating a field (of a bit value) to indicate if the row is "archived" or not rather than duplicating the tables?  That way in the query I would just say to find records whose "archive" flag is set to FALSE or something like that..?  I know that SQL Server (and MySQL for that matter) can handle millions of rows in matter of seconds, but was mainly concerned with speed of running queries once the table gets to be large--say over 500,000 rows.

Comment: To improve performance you analyse the workload (whatever queries you are using) and then apply indexes as practical. Don't complicate your design with an archive flag that needs to be included in every query. It'll just complicate things.